# Formattable R package: conditionaly formatting the cells' content on the basis of a numeric threshold

Tags: r, html-table, formattable

I have a dataframe like the following

```
mydata <- structure(list(Wife = c(15.972, 12.715, 8.333, 6.276, 2.179, 
-1.408, -1.649, -4.647, -7.039, -5.299, -7.411, -9.776, -9.612
), Alternating = c(-2.622, -0.548, -1.331, 3.9, -1.802, 2.08, 
1.481, 9.53, 7.709, -0.953, -4.823, -4.878, -5.245), Husband = c(-7.012, 
-5.823, -3.99, -3.324, -5.828, -4.869, -3.941, 0.515, 9.551, 
-0.868, 4.843, 24.544, -5.812), Jointly = c(-8.283, -7.569, -4.048, 
-6.564, 4.418, 4.284, 4.157, -3.006, -7.306, 7.066, 7.086, -8.306, 
19.397)), row.names = c("Laundry", "Main_meal", "Dinner", "Breakfeast", 
"Tidying", "Dishes", "Shopping", "Official", "Driving", "Finances", 
"Insurance", "Repairs", "Holidays"), class = "data.frame")
```

which lists the chi-square adjusted standardized residuals. Using the 'formattable' R package, I managed to get the below table (more nicely formatted than in the R console):

[image]

**Issue**

I cannot find a viable option to conditionally formatting some cells according to the size of the residual. What I am after is (for example) to have in GREEN the cells whose residual is larger than +1.96, and in RED those whose residual is smaller than -1.96.
I have indeed consulted the package's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html), with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)

mydata <- structure(list(Wife = c(
  15.972, 12.715, 8.333, 6.276, 2.179,
  -1.408, -1.649, -4.647, -7.039, -5.299, -7.411, -9.776, -9.612
), Alternating = c(
  -2.622, -0.548, -1.331, 3.9, -1.802, 2.08,
  1.481, 9.53, 7.709, -0.953, -4.823, -4.878, -5.245
), Husband = c(
  -7.012,
  -5.823, -3.99, -3.324, -5.828, -4.869, -3.941, 0.515, 9.551,
  -0.868, 4.843, 24.544, -5.812
), Jointly = c(
  -8.283, -7.569, -4.048,
  -6.564, 4.418, 4.284, 4.157, -3.006, -7.306, 7.066, 7.086, -8.306,
  19.397
)), row.names = c(
  "Laundry", "Main_meal", "Dinner", "Breakfeast",
  "Tidying", "Dishes", "Shopping", "Official", "Driving", "Finances",
  "Insurance", "Repairs", "Holidays"
), class = "data.frame")



style_ci <- function(x) {
  case_when(x > 1.96 ~ "green", x < -1.96 ~ "red", TRUE ~ "black")
}

formattable(mydata, list(
  Wife = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = style_ci(Wife))),
  Alternating = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = style_ci(Alternating))),
  Husband = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = style_ci(Husband))),
  Jointly = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = style_ci(Jointly)))
))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer, very useful. Would there be any possibility to make that code more flexible by referencing to the columns' index, instead of using the columns' name? I ask because I might need to use that approach when the table of residuals is produced by a function, and one cannot directly use the columns' names (coz those may change from time to time). Making reference to the columns' index would be needed.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191851/applying-a-formattable-format-to-all-columns-at-once